# Linux: audio streaming server capable of converting tracks to MP3 on-the-fly

Tags: linux, streaming, audio, convert

I'm looking for an audio streaming solution capable of providing content from a folder (recursively) with on-the-fly convertion to MP3 (or whatever) with a constant bitrate: from other MP3s and FLAC.
It will be also nice if the solution provides simple stream management: next/prev track at least.

I've tried Ampache, but it does not convert anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would [firefly](http://www.fireflymediaserver.org/) fit your bill? According to the website:

Features

There are a number of features that differentiate Firefly Media Server from those other servers, and here is a partial list:

```
* Support for running on unix/POSIX platforms
* Support for Windows (beta versions)
* Support for Mac OSX (coming soon!)
* Support for on-the-fly transcoding of OGG, FLAC, Apple Lossless, and WMA (beta versions)
* Web-based configuration
* Support for user-created smart playlists (beta versions)
* Integrates with iTunes library including reading playlists
* Supports serving streaming radio stations
* Did I mention fast?
* Under active development!
```

Comment: In Ubuntu the package is called `mt-daapd`. Alas, currently it's only able to convert media files to WAV before streaming, but it's nice pick! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I used to use [Jinzora](http://en.jinzora.com/features) which handles transcoding and all kinds of audio formats and has similar operation to Ampache.  It has been a while since I used it, and I never did transcoding but it might be worth checking out.

Comment: Jinzora is a PHP solution that can work with/without MySQL database. Simple installation (copy-paste + installer script), nice interface, can read tracks' tags. Provides contents by generating *.m3u playlist file with external URLs. Nice, thanks :)